# How to upgrade to a new distribution with encrypted home folder?

Tags: upgrade, encryption

Today I've heard of 17.04 coming, and started making plans for an upgrade (I'm on 16.04).

However, one thing seems like it may cause trouble - my encrypted swap and home folder. Will it?

Previously I reinstalled my Ubuntu (after *accidentally* deleting python, nautilus, and maybe terminal) using the same user name and password, and my home folder works just fine.

**Do I have to manually backup and then copy my encrypted home folder for an upgrade to 17.04?**

**Caveat**: I'm aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61619/upgrading-ubuntu-with-encrypted-home), but it's pretty old and doesn't necessarily address my case.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything other than _upgrade_ it should automatically move over to your new version. And as that post said _the issue was fixed_.

Comment: "Do I have to manually backup" You will make a backup of your personal files before you do this. Regard;ess of whatever happens next.  "and then copy my encrypted home folder for an upgrade to 17.04?" Nope. See @george 's comment :)

Comment: YES __please backup__ that's always the best thing to do and also the right thing to do..

Comment: Are you planning going from an LTS release to regular one, that's what you're saying?

Comment: @xangua  -  I though of a more general situation, though if you think there'll be differences it'd be nice to hear them.

Comment: 17.04 is not released yet. Until its release it's a development version. 16.04 is LTS and the default setting is to suggest release upgrade **only** for the next LTS release  (18.04). In order to do an online upgrade to the dev version you'd need firt to upgrade to 16.10 and from there issue a command to force upgrade to the development branch. **Definitely not recommended**.